# Java quiz not working need assistance with if statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I am making a simple quiz in Java, however, I am running into some trouble.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class quiz {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );
        String q1 = "London";
        String a1;
        int q2 = 20;
        int a2;
        String q3 = "Java";
        String a3;
        int score = 0;

        System.out.println( "What is the capital of England? ");
        a1 = keyboard.next();
        if(a1 == q1) {
            score + 1;
            System.out.println( "Correct!");
        }
        else if {
            System.out.println( "WRONG!" );
        }

        System.out.println( "What is 10 + 10?" );
        a2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        if(a2 == q2) {
            score + 1;
            System.out.println( "Correct!" );
        }
        else if {
            System.out.println( "WRONG" );
        }

        System.out.println( "What langauge is kevin learning?" );
        a3 = keyboard.next();
        if(a3 == q3) {
            score + 1;
            System.out.println( "Correct!" );
        }
        else if {
            System.out.println( "WRONG" );
        }

        System.out.println( "Your total marks were" score );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is *some trouble*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Read [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) first.

Comment: What is wrong exactly? Maybe you could put that instead of "blah blah blah blah..."

Comment: Your problem is blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah, the recommended solution is to blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.

Comment: This does not compile, you should read the compiler errors for hints on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to compare String using their `equals` method `==` does not compare the String, but the object's location in memory.
So, instead of `if(a1 == q1)` use `if(a1.equals(q1))`

EDIT: here is the workig code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class quiz {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );
        String q1 = "London";
        String a1;
        int q2 = 20;
        int a2;
        String q3 = "Java";
        String a3;
        int score = 0;

        System.out.println( "What is the capital of England? ");
        a1 = keyboard.next();
        if(a1.equals(q1)) {
            score += 1;
            System.out.println( "Correct!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println( "WRONG!" );
        }

        System.out.println( "What is 10 + 10?" );
        a2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        if(a2 == q2) {
            score += 1;
            System.out.println( "Correct!" );
        }
        else {
            System.out.println( "WRONG" );
        }

        System.out.println( "What langauge is kevin learning?" );
        a3 = keyboard.next();
        if(a3.equals(q3)) {
      score += 1;
            System.out.println( "Correct!" );
        }
    else {
            System.out.println( "WRONG" );
        }

    System.out.println("Your total marks were" + score);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried that but when i try to compile it in cmd it says 29 errors

Comment: Well then you also need to fix those errors. If it is so many, it is usually some } or { missing somewhere. I'll have a look and will update my answer.

Comment: its alright i fixed everythintg thanks though

Comment: updated your code to remove compile errors and fixed the string compare I first hinted.
Good luck on your way to learning this language.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect `String` comparison:

```
if(a1 == q1)
```

should be:

```
if(a1.equals(q1))
```

same story with:

```
if(a3 == q3)
```